# How can i navigate from one screen to other screen in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to create navigation from one screen to another screen. I used the instructions from react navigation. Below is my expo snack link. full code are there.

LINK: https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/68d88a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit https://snack.expo.dev/@horstleung/smiling-chocolates

Questions you have:

1. your component is not exported, you may take reference from [here](https://javascript.info/import-export)

```
import React from 'react';
import Documents from './Documents';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Home from './Home';


import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import DetailOne from './DetailOne';
import DetailTwo from './DetailTwo';
import App from '../App';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const DetailStack = ({navigation}) => (
  <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={App}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="DetailOne" component={DetailOne}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="DetailTwo" component={DetailTwo}/>
  </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

2. You don't need one more `NavigationContainer`
3. In your DetailStack,  that should be Home component, not App

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={App}/>
```